# dynamically select options of multiselect from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i tried to automatically select the value of multiselect box using data retrieved from database, but its not working...

this is the code for html multiselect

```
<select name="category" id="category" multiple="multiple" class="select validate[required]" style="width:100%">

</select>
```

at page load i dynamically load options for multiselect from database (mysql)

```
$.ajax({
        url:'search/category.php',
        type:'POST',
    data:{cat_id:1},   //1 means jobs category
    async:true,
    success: function(data){
    $("#category").html(data);
   }
});
```

but if i have to auto select value in multiselect its not working

```
 <?php

    $qry ="select tags from posts where id='$id'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    $tags = $row['tags'];
    ?>


<script>

  $(function(){
           $("#category").val(<?php echo $tags; ?>);     //example: .val(3);
        }

</script>
```

Comment: where is the php being called from? is the php script you put in your question in category.php?

Comment: Why are you only fetching one row? If there are multiple tags, don't you need to fetch multiple rows? Or is `tags` a comma-separated list? Then you need to explode it and loop to create all the options. (this is poor database design, BTW).

Answer (score 0):

ajax is correct but you need to echo select options correctly

in category function try this :

```
foreach ($tags as $tag=>$val) {
echo "<option value=".$val." > ".$tag."</option>";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are just missing the quotes in your $("#category").val(); line. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p8qAN/) fiddle out.

```
$("#category").val( "'" + <?php echo $tags; ?> + "'");
```

should get it to work

Comment: This isn't right. Since `$tags` isn't quoted, you can't concatenate it with `+`. It should just be `.val('<?php echo $tags; ?>')`.

Comment: Sorry. I am no php coder. I only wanted to point out the missing quotes.